the selection of symmetrically encrypted tables is very slow PostgreSQL 11?
There is a table with statements. The columns with the number, surname, first name, patronymic are symmetrically encrypted in it. I make a selection like this:
SELECT s.id,
sym_dec(s.parent_iin,@encrkey) as parent_iin,
sym_dec(s.iin,@encrkey) as iin,sym_dec(s.lastname,@encrkey) as lastname,sym_dec(s.firstname,@encrkey) as firstname,sym_dec(s.middlename,@encrkey) as middlename,
s.birth_date,s.group_type,s.privilege,s.disorder,s.queue_ident,s.queue_number,s.queue_number2,s.create_date,s.create_time,s.status,s.interested,
s.parent_lastname,s.parent_firstname,s.parent_middlename,s.tel,s.email,
s.interested_date,s.interested_time,s.ident_number,s.email,s.tel,s.correct_org,s.status_date,s.status_time,s.disorder_doc,s.referral_bin,c_s.*
FROM ddo.statements as s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ddo.code_statstatus as c_s ON c_s.code=s.status
WHERE  
sym_dec(s.parent_iin,@encrkey)=@ParentIIN 
ORDER by s.create_date asc,s.create_time asc

as you can see from the query, the columns for each record are decrypted when selected. When more than 1000 records are selected, the query runs for a very long time and at the end the application has a Max Pool Size error of 100
postgresql configuration
max_connections = 9999
shared_buffers = 257792MB
effective_cache_size = 773376MB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 13200kB
huge_pages = try
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2

I can't find a solution

What is a "max pool size error"? Is that from the database?

Well, you are asking the database to decrypt every row to find ones with that @ParentIIN, no doubt it can be slow. If you need queries on parent_iin, but need it to be confidential, I'd consider a cryptographic (one-way) hash of it, and query based on that...

@laurenz-albe .NET Core log:  Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise 'Max Pool Size' (currently 100) or 'Timeout' (currently 15 seconds) in your connection string.
---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.

@AKX you can use a link or an example?

@testovtest No link or example. Choose a cryptographic hash, such as SHA-256. Insert a column (say, parent_iin_hash) containing sha256(sym_dec(s.parent_iin,@encrkey)) (optionally add salt if you're worried about rainbow tables and so on). Create an index on it if you like. When querying, run the same hashing for the query parameter, say, @hashed_parent_iin. Query with s.parent_iin_hash=@hashed_parent_iin.

Could you encrypt @ParentIIN and check it against s.parent_iin like in s.parent_iin = sym_enc(@ParentIIN, @encrkey)? As the right hand side is just a constant, this needs only one encryption operation for the whole statement instead of one decryption operation per row in the table. This should already be a massive speedup for the WHERE filter. If you additionally put an index onto parent_iin, this should get even faster. I think the effect should be similar to @AKX suggestion but without an extra column
